# Cast a Typed list<> to be prepared for DataAdapter Update

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, generic-list

We Have this :

```
List<Person> listPerson ;
```

Want to use the Data of **listPerson** in a `SqlDataAdapter`

something similar to :

```
adapter.Update(listPerson);
```

*Possibilities maybe casting and converting **listPerson** into `List<DataRow>` or A DataTable or whatever else which be acceptable for adapter's Update method ...*

LinQ or any more robust code is appreciated,

Which way do you suggest ?

Comment: Why detour over the DataAdapter?

Comment: Hi Henk, at first I tried entities, but there is a situation which I should do some heavy multi-threaded processes, And EF lacks this. Now the process is done with a dataset and and the list I mentioned in the question, now I want to return this heavy list back to the database.

Comment: Why don't you just add the `Person` call directly to the `DataTable`?  What I mean by this you can define the values the `DataTable` holds.  Write a method that extracts the information from the `Person` class so it will hold it.  I did this to hold a custom class for a project I worked on.  All you do is grab the `DataTable` and go through each entry when you need to retrieve the objects again.

Comment: These are heavy analysis on each record, After I found I couldn't use EF caused by it's lackness on Thread-Safety I went for Dataset and offline working and filling a Typed List, this way the performance increased about 10 times more , Now want to return it back to the database, I could cast it back via LinQ select or some iterations, If you have any better idea please show a piece of code, which would be more helpful, anyway I want to see any preferable method all you suggest

Comment: Both the answers were helpful, unfortunately although I liked @HatSoft way and was trying to do this in a similar manner but still that was incorrect and needed more linq and a mapping part to match to the database columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest I can think of:

[DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable.aspx)

You'll probably need a lambda to convert a Person to a PersonRow

Comment: thanks, It should do the job could you make it simplified by giving 2 lines of code on my example instance ? maybe that be better than MSDN sample on this. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The SqlDataAdapter.Update Method can take parameter of types

> 1) Update(DataRow[])
>   2) Update(DataSet)
>   3) Update(DataTable)
>   4) Update(DataRow[], DataTableMapping)
>   5) Update(DataSet, String)

So the easiest way as you already have a list of person will be :

```
        DataRow[] personRows= Persons.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray();
        sqlDataAdapter.Update(personRows);
```

Hope this helps ....

Comment: Will try it, sorry I could answer about one hour later, thanks

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, but unfortunately it caused this error : InvalidCastException : "Unable to cast object of type 'MP.Person' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'."

Comment: Sorry for being late answering, This is not correct my friend cause it should be mapped to the DataRow we have, I will edit the post to point it out